# How do I hide wireframes of other objects, showing the wireframe of only one?

Tags: edit-mode, wireframe

As pictured: [image]

What setting did he toggle and how do I do it so it looks like his layout too?

Edit: My current layout is to the right, his is to the left

Comment: Hit Z choose wireframe.

Comment: My layout is to the right, the tutorial guide is pictured to the left. Choosing wireframe via Z or clicking my way there shows wireframe on everything and it is confusing.

Comment: I guess it's Optimal Display in Subsurf modifier settings for objects, was asked here already several times. There's also [fade inactive geometry](https://developer.blender.org/rBea6cd1c8f05)

Comment: I literally just found the solution too! Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching comments on youtube for hours I found a few people having same issue, OPTIMAL DISPLAY [image: OPTIMAL DISPLAY] on SUBSURF MODIF should be UNTICKED [image: UNTICKED], and Xray dropdown under Geometry WIREFRAME should be set to 0.5 [image: under Xray dropdown under Geometry WIREFRAME should be set to 0.5] to get the same display as Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've switched to *Wireframe* mode you can disable the *X-Ray* mode, and you can select your object and in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display > Display As > Wire*. This way, only this object is transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select that particular object <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> to hide all other objects in *Edit Mode* and <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> for unhiding.

Comment: Shift+H is to hide everything but selection.